# How to rotate y-axis tick labels in Pandas barplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For Pandas.DataFrame plot() fn, the 'rot' keyword argument rotates the x-axis ticks specifically. So how does one rotate the y-axis ticks?
There's some documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which gives the anticipated syntax for the 'rot' argument for either xticks or yticks, but lacking of an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate axes ticks, it's convenient to use matplotlib feature.
After importing matplotlib as **'plt'**, you just have to write:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=specify_here_a_value)
plt.yticks(rotation=specify_here_a_value)
plt.show()
```

It will do the work for you. Coming to the question you asked, **'rot'** keyword takes argument or rotates the axis based on the **type of graph** as said in the documentation:

> rot : int, default None

> Rotation for ticks (xticks for vertical, yticks for horizontal plots)

I think if plot is **vertical**, it rotates **xticks** and if it is **horizontal** it rotates **yticks**.

Matplotlib provides the better way as written above. I find it much more effective.

Answer (score 0):

##### Example

```
axs= pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(numericData, figsize = (colNo,colNo))
    
    for i in range(colNo):
        vert = axs[i,0]
        vert.yaxis.label.set_rotation(0)
        vert.xaxis.label.set_ha('right')
        vert.set_yticks(())
        h = axs[colNo-1, i]
        h.xaxis.label.set_rotation(90)
        h.set_xticks(())
```